# When does a std::vector move in memory?

Tags: c++, stdvector

I know that a push_back can change the memory location of a std::vector when its capacity is exceeded. But can other operations do that?

In particular, is it possible that the manipulation of other vectors impact the location of the first one?

I think I observed this behaviour. Using a pointer to an element of the vector eventually makes a segfault while I don't modify the vector at all. I am unable to make a minimal example because it seems to be closely related to the rest of the memory management of my code.

Comment: "Using a pointer to an element of the vector eventually makes a segfault while I don't modify the vector at all." - sounds surprising to me. what compiler?

Comment: `std::vector` would normally manage its memory. What sort of memory management do you have in the rest of your code?

Comment: @Asu i use gcc48.

Comment: @flatmouse I'm not sure what you mean by memory management. I mostly use vector, and very light use of mallocs.